# Is it possible to attach Oracle database files after a clean install

Tags: oracle, restore, oracle-10g

I had an Oracle 10g instance on my Win2008R2 server. Unfortunately, the server crashed and we had to re-install the operating system on the C: drive. The oracle files are on drives other than C.

The other drives (except C) are restored from disk backups. I don't have a dump file, I only have the Oracle data files such as USERS01.DBF and the Oracle control files.

Now I am trying to find a way to install Oracle again on the server but I am just wondering about how I can attach the current.DBF files to the new Oracle instance? Is this possible? If so, how can I attach the current?DBF files to Oracle?

Currently, there is no "OracleService" on `services.msc` and no listener as well. But previous the previous Oracle instance was installed on the F drive so I still have the Oracle binaries and data files on the F drive.

I would really appreciate it if you could provide any information about this.

Comment: Did you try the recovery from the manual https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/recov002.htm#i1037378

Comment: Do you have the PFILE or SPFILE? Do you have the Control files? Log files? Archive log files?

Comment: From the rare times I used Oracle on Windows, I seem to remember one could create the service from the commandline.  Since it seems that's the only thing you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your database consists of a control file that points to the datafiles, temporary files and the redo log files.

What you now need is an Oracle instance that is going to serve the requests for that database. The Oracle instance needs a parameter file that has the control_files parameter pointing to your control file[s]. On windows you will find this file in %ORACLE_HOME%\database\ and the textual form of this file is just a texfile with parameters.

On windows you have the oradim utility that creates the oracle service. One of the parameters for oradim is the location of the parameter file. Smartest is to use the spfile for this because it can be maintained from the database, where the text file has to be maintained using an editor. Now a days we expect the binary version since it also maintains the more dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 0):

ORADIM is what you need: [Creating an Oracle service on Windows](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Creating_an_Oracle_service_on_Windows)